# invoke_signed mint_to with native multisig

Tags: mint, multisig

I'm trying to mint from a program with a multisig authority.

The idea basically is to have a token-mint with multisig (1-N) authority [created with native solana-spl `createMultisig`.

I put the program PDA address as one of the multisigners, but doesn't work...

```
use anchor_spl::token_2022::spl_token_2022::instruction::mint_to;
....
let ix = mint_to(
        &ctx.accounts.token_program,
        ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
        ctx.accounts.to.key(),
        ctx.accounts.multisig.key(),
        &[&multisig.key()],
        amount,
    )?;
    anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
        &ix,
        &[
            ctx.accounts.to.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.multisig.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.pool.to_account_info(), // PDA signer
        ],
        compute_seed(ctx.accounts.pool), // <= this works without the multisig authority
    )
```

I tried a bunch of different combinations for the authority and the signers array, always get escalated priv, or "can't compute signer address". In the test file I played with the `.remainingAccounts` with isWritable/isSigner without luck...

If anyone can point me to a real example or where is my issue would be awesome =D
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close! You just need to pass in the pool account as the signer for the multisig, ie:

```
    let ix = mint_to(
        &ctx.accounts.token_program,
        ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
        ctx.accounts.to.key(),
        ctx.accounts.multisig.key(),
        &[&ctx.accounts.pool.key()],
        amount,
    )?;
```

This will properly mark the pool account as a required signer, and allow `invoke_signed` to work.

Comment: It's not working like this I already tried... 
Checked a bunch of alternatives like "re marking" accounts in ix and accounts without luck... 
Like:
```
  all_acc = ctx.accounts.to_account_infos()
      .iter()
      .map(|acc| {
          let mut acx = acc.clone();
          if acx.key == &self.pool.key() {
              acx.is_signer = true;
... 
```